# How can I run my Web application in background?

Tags: database, background

I want to fetch some big data from the database API. it takes time (more than 5minutes maybe), but I want to keep my connection with the API. even if (I or User) closed web browser.

Can someone help me out?

Show me the way, please.

BTW, I'm using API with JavaScript, Java based API server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a curl command and run it in background using nohup on a unix machine

like

```
nohup curl https://xxxxxx &
```

you need to explore a bit more how you ll make the same request using curl which are you making using the browser
this will run it in background even if you shut your shell terminal until your unix server is running

Comment: if I use curl like you said, can i see progress how it progressed also result?

Comment: the o/p of nohup command gets stored in a nohup.out file in the directory where you will run the command , so if your curl is generating any response it ll get logged over there.